# Expectation of $X_t^2$ in ARCH(1) model

Tags: time-series, expected-value, garch

Given the ARCH(1) model

\begin{aligned}
X_{t} &= \sigma_{t}Z_{t} \\
\sigma^{2}_{t} &= \alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1}X^{2}_{t-1}
\end{aligned}

where the process $Z_{t} \sim^{\text{iid}}$ are random variables with mean 0 and variance 1, how does one calculate

$$\mathbb{E}[X^{2}_{t} |?$$

Comment: I think you have a typo in the last part. Also, does this question deserve to be tagged with the `self-study` tag?

Comment: Related question ["Expectation of $X_t^2$ in GARCH(1,1) model"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339309/conditional-expectation-garch1-1-model).