# Expectation of $X_t^2$ in GARCH(1,1) model

Tags: time-series, garch, conditional-expectation

Given a GARCH(1,1) model

\begin{aligned}
X_{t} &= \sigma_{t}Z_{t} \\
\sigma^{2}_{t} &= \omega + \alpha_{1}X^{2}_{t-1} + \beta_{1}\sigma^{2}_{t-1}
\end{aligned}

with $Z_{t} \sim i.i.d(0,1)$:

\begin{aligned}
X_{t}^2 &= \sigma_{t}^2 Z_{t}^2 \\
&= (\omega + \alpha_{1}X^{2}_{t-1} + \beta_{1}\sigma^{2}_{t-1}) Z_t^2.
\end{aligned}

How does one write out the conditional expectation $$E[X_t^2|X_{t-1}^2, X_{t-2}^2, ...]$$

as a summation of alpha, expectation of alpha, beta, etc.?

Comment: Related question ["Expectation of $X_t^2$ in ARCH(1) model"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339245/expectation-of-x-t2-in-arch1-model).

Comment: @RichardHardy, what I mean was that you can calculate the variance from, what's known at $t-1$, it's not stochastic at this point. need to clean my language

Answer (score 3):

GARCH was made to address varying volatility in financial and economic *return* time series. Note, that the returns on these series usually have very small or no drift at all. Hence, $E[X_t]\approx 0$ and subsequently $\operatorname{Var}\left[X_t\right]\approx X_t^2$ is a good estimate of the observed volatility.

This will explain the form of the second equation in GARCH. Compare it to a typical exponential smoothing:
$$s_t=\lambda x_t+(1-\lambda)s_{t-1}$$

So, the idea was to construct a process where the previous volatility $\sigma_{t-1}$ for time $t-1$ gets constantly updated by the new observed volatility estimate $X_{t-1}^2$ that defines the volatility for the next time step $\sigma_{t}$.

Note, that at time $t-1$ all terms on the right hand side of your second equation of GARCH are already observed, which means that $\sigma_t^2$ is deterministic as time $t-1$. The random draw of the return $X_t$ happens in the first equation using this known (at time $t-1$) volatility $\sigma_t$.

When you understand the background of GARCH it should be clear that the answer to your question must be $\sigma_t^2$

Answer (score 2):

As you have already written:

$
E[X^2_t | X^2_{t-1},...] = E[\sigma^2_t Z^2_t| X^2_{t-1},...] = E[(w+\alpha_1 X^2_{t-1}+\beta_1 \sigma^2_{t-1})Z^2_t| X^2_{t-1},...]
$

Now, by linearity of the expectation and knowing that $Z_t$ is independent from $X_{t-1},...$ you have:

$
= w E[Z^2_t] + \alpha_1 X^2_{t-1} E[Z^2_t] + \beta_1 \sigma^2_{t-1} E[Z^2_t] = \sigma^2_t
$

since $E[Z^2_t] = \operatorname{Var}(Z_t) = 1$.

The reason is that once you condition on the past history of $X^2_{t-1},...$ you are treating both $X^2_{t-1}$ and $\sigma^2_{t-1}$ as constant.

Comment: How is $Z_t$ independent of $X_t$ if $X_t=\sigma_t Z_t$?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @RichardHardy. I edited the answer.